# How to run bundled circuits with a different number of shots per circuit on QISKIT?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Say I have two basic circuits to run, call them qc1 and qc2 (as in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUt4YKQEUco&ab_channel=Qiskit). On QISKIT I can run them in the same job, to save overhead time, and also spend less time in the queue. Is there any way I can use a different number of shots per circuit?
So for example I can run both circuits with the following code:

```
qc_list=[qc1,1c2]
job=execute(qc_list,Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),shots=1000)
```

However, this runs both circuits with the same number of shots. I tried  to run something like this to use a different number of shots for each circuit:

```
job=execute(qc_list,Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),shots=[1000,2000])
```

But this returns an error saying that shots only takes integers as its argument. Does anyone know how to pass a list of shots alongside a list of circuits?

If not it is not a disaster, I can simply use the maximum number of shots and throw away some results, but this feels very wasteful, so I would rather not do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. As you can see [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/execution), if you send several circuits on the same job, then the job will execute by iterating over every circuit for each shot, i.e. the first shot will be done for every circuit, then the second shot, then the third, and so on.